# Wordpress qTranslate and sub-domain help needed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, qtranslate

OK I have my website running Wordpress at http://www.visualise.ca/ and I installed the qTranslate plugin to have a bilingual installation. If you visit http://www.visualise.ca/?lang=fr you will see the french version of my website.

The problem is that it messes up my AJAX scripts so I would like to use the qTranslate option that allows me to have my french version in a sub-domain at http://fr.visualise.ca/ instead.

When I activate this option the http://fr.visualise.ca/ returns blank (Server not found) so here are my questions:

1) I guess I have to use .htaccess ? If yes, what's the syntax ?

2) I created sub-domain fr.visualise.ca and made it point to the root document folder of my Wordpress installation, is that ok?

Many thanks for your time and help

**UPDATE: Actually it was working I had to use and create a sub-domain for fr.www.visualise.ca instead of fr.visualise.ca ... Which is kind of ugly :-/**

Comment: If you did #2, then why do you need #1?

Comment: Also, why would you expect to work when using a subdomain vs. just the appended querystring parameter?

Comment: Actually it was working I had to use and create a sub-domain for http://fr.www.visualise.ca/ instead of http://fr.visualise.ca/ ... Which is kind of ugly :-/

Comment: that is ugly. sorry I can't help on how to modify that subdomain format. You might want to repost and target your question specifically to subdomains. Possibly on serverfault.com instead.

Comment: What I did is to use my wordpress at visualise.ca instead of www.visualise.ca and and I have fr.visualise.ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make sure that the http://fr.visualise.ca subdomain exists and is map to right folder on the web server (same folder as the visualise.ca domain)

Answer (score 1):

You will add to the CNAME records to your DNS-Server or set a "catch all" like *.yourdomain.com